# How to loop through Object and then get IndexOf string such as A, B..and then convert to value if A=1, b=2

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
var graph= {
node: [
  { id:"A",  
    name:"A" 
  },
  { id:"B",  
    name:"B" 
  }
]
}

var yourInput = document.getElementById("vertext").value
// The user inputs A or B..

var convertToInt = graph.node.indexOf(yourInput)+1;
// I am always getting 0 ..
```

My solution: I looped through graph node object and check the indexOf the input if is A, B..and then convert the user input to integer value based on IndexOf alphabet present in object array.

Please can somebody explain what am I doing wrong here..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to check a value against a property of each of your array elements, [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is the appropriate tool instead of Array.indexOf.

```
var convertToInt = graph.node.findIndex(e => e.id == yourInput) + 1;
```

The inner function checks the id property of each of the array elements against yourInput.  You could easily modify it to check the name property instead, or do just about any comparison you can think of.

```js
var graph = {
  node: [{
      id: "A",
      name: "A"
    },
    {
      id: "B",
      name: "B"
    }
  ]
}

document.getElementById("vertext").onchange = function() {
  var yourInput = document.getElementById("vertext").value
  // The user inputs A or B..
  var convertToInt = graph.node.findIndex(e => e.id == yourInput) + 1;
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = convertToInt;
};
```

```html
<select id="vertext">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<br>
Index is <span id="output"><span>
```

Comment: Hi James, I tried your solution using regular function as below                        
   var convertToInt = graph.node.findIndex(function(e){
        e.id == vertex1 + 1;
    });  //when i console.log convertToInt I get -1, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @manojkarmocha You're missing the `return` statement: `return e.id == yourInput;`. Also, you shouldn't add 1 to it, the ID is a string.

Comment: @manojkarmocha Arrow functions add `return` automatically in the simple format, but if you write a traditional function you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: @barmar i used return and removed 1 but still i get -1

Comment: @manojkarmocha I've added a snippet using James's arrow function. You should be able to replace that with a traditional function and it should still work.

Comment: @manojkarmocha Are you sure the user is entering an uppercase letter `A` not `a`?

Comment: @barmar the strange thing is the snippet sometime works if i refresh my browser I also have a onclick function in button. I don't know why but i feel there is some issue with value field. Its weird.

Comment: @manojkarmocha You need to post the whole code that you're trying to run, then we can see what you're doing wrong.